# Run Kibana 4.1.1 as a service on CentOS 6.5

Tags: elasticsearch, centos6, kibana-4

I recently upgraded our Elasticsearch server to 1.7.0 and now tried to upgrade Kibana to 4.1.1 but stuck with the service startup.

I have not seen any documentation on how to start the kibana 4.1.x as a service on CentOs 6.5 but only seen for CentOS7

Anyone done this install on CentOS 6.5?

**Update**

See [post](http://sysads.co.uk/2015/07/install-elasticsearch-1-7-x-and-kibana-4-1-x-on-centos-6-5/) for tutorial I had to put together on how to install Elasticsearch 1.7.x and Kibana 4.1.x on CentOS 6.5

Comment: Using CentOS7 tutorial you can do in CentOS 6.5 :)

Comment: @YuvrajGupta how does that work. For Kibana to run as a service on CentOS 7, you need systemd which isn't available on CentOS 6 - [Article](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/run-kibana-as-service-on-centos/23971/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Kibana use this repository:-
https://github.com/cjcotton/init-kibana

Comment: Great... You can post the solution of yours so that it can be helpful for others :)

Comment: I have added a [tutorial](http://sysads.co.uk/2015/07/install-elasticsearch-1-7-x-and-kibana-4-1-x-on-centos-6-5/) I put together for this. Hopefully this comes in handy for others with similar challenge

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: **This is for CentOS 7**

Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-centos-7) wonderful step by step tutorial for installing ELK on CentOS. It has steps to run all three components Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana - as services. I used the Ubuntu variant of the tutorial and works just fine for me.

Comment: Even if the Kibana versions are different, you might want to try that for your version and it should work.

Comment: How does this help the topic for CentOS 6.5

Comment: It might be different CentOS version. But I guess, things work similarly if the OS is the same?

Comment: If you took time to read the question, you will understand why I asked this question in first place.

Comment: Yes I did see it. And just for the sake of trying, did you give it a shot? You have not mentioned on the question if you tried anything at all. As I understand "I could not find is" not something specific that you tried.

Comment: PS: I am not at all with CentOS, so not entirely sure about the comment you made on your question about "systemd" not present on the CentOS 6.5

Comment: Just found a few SO posts saying: "systemd is not available for CentOS6.5 and one shout not even try installing it." I have been using the above mentioned post and I am new to everything: Linux, ELK and so was just making sure, share the resources that have been helpful to me. Completely my bad! Pardon me! :)

Comment: Hey buddy, you don't need to. We all are here to learn :D. Thanks for the link, others might find it handy when working on CentOS 7